# How to change a list [1,2,3] into 1 2 3 with spaces in between?

Tags: python, arraylist

I created a list

```py
x = list(range(0,5))
```

which gives the result `[0,1,2,3,4]` but I want to convert it as `0 1 2 3 4`

How do I do that?

Comment: You will need to write code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: my bad, this is my first time posting here I'll try to add codes next time!

Comment: @Jeffy, you want it to convert to `0 1 2 3 4` and do ..... ?

Comment: well I just started learning python so I was practicing and wanted to find out the second-highest score from a list of n integers I was able to put down the logic but my output was a list and the problem statement wanted me to unpack the list and write it using spaces so I was not able to get that part

Answer (score 0):

Try using `*` to unpack the list

```
print(*[1,2,3]) # -> 1 2 3
```

Comment: yes, I was searching for this one, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
print(' '.join(myList))
```